# Accessing a symbol that is already on stage through as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have several symbols in the library (using Flash CS5), and all of these instances have a custom base class set with a method (lets say x()).

I have the symbols already positioned on the stage using the IDE, and I wanted to access them through as3 and run the method. 
I understand that you can instantiate a new object of an item in the library, but how would I access the object that are on the stage already?

currently I'm doing something like the following:

```
var objectList:Array = new Array();
objectList.push(InstanceName1);
objectList.push(InstanceName2);
objectList.push(InstanceName3);

objectList[0].x(); //trying to run the method on the existing Symbol
```

However, flash returns an error saying that the object does not have method x(). Also looking through the debugger, it doesn't seem like the item pushed is an instance of the base class, rather it says (prototype). This works of course if I were to create a new instance of each, but I would rather access the ones that are on the stage already. 
How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them an instance name like this: [image]

Then use that name when pushing them to your array.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this step, thanks. but I'm still getting an error. let me be specific: I have a symbol named Icon that is linked to a class named IconObject. I have instances of the Icon symbol named respectively Icon1, 2, and 3. now in the as3, I am trying to do what I put above, pushing Icon1, Icon2,... and I'm trying to access a method named setIcons() that is in the IconObject class

Comment: Try and use UpperCase names for your classes and symbols, and lowerCase for instances. It's way less confusing. If you have your classes and symbols linked up properly your code should work.

Comment: ahh, setting the instance names to lowercase allowed me to see that those instances weren't accessible from the class I was trying to call them from, which isn't the document class. I'm assuming stage instances are only visible to the document class? I was able to access it from there easily. thanks for the help!